# Image and \captionof on different pages

Tags: captions, koma-script

The following example places the image on page 1, the corresponding caption on page 2. Is there a way to prevent LaTeX from doing so?

```
\documentclass[12pt, ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3] aaa \\ bbb \\ bbb \\ bbb

\begin{center}
\rule{10cm}{6.5cm}
\captionof{figure}{Some arbitrary caption}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: on different pages]

Comment: captionof should usually be in a minipage along with the image to prevent it being separated

Comment: good point, I was not aware of this. I would accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\captionof` should usually be in a `minipage` along with the image to prevent it being separated